# Publishing/Creating a poll from an android app to facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

There is an application in facebook called poll(opinion poll), where you can give a **question** and some **options**. After you create the poll, others can start to vote. Can I create the poll in my android app and publish it in facebook? i.e the user will give his facebook login credentials and teh app will create the poll on his behalf. Are there any such API's?

Comment: The only way to work with Facebook from android is through the Facebook SDK. Check out their developer site. And check out their [Scrumptious](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/) app tutorial. I had a lot of trouble working with the facebook sdk, there never seems to be a lot of answers or tutorials on the subject. So, the only way really is trial and error.

Comment: @AndroidStudent : I saw the tutorials. It is too big. Anyway I will read it. Just want to know if, what I want is possible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  The relevant documentation is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/question/

To do this on your android app, you need to add our Facebook SDK for Android to your app.  Once you do so, to create a question you just need to do the following

1. Authenticate the user via Facebook to get a valid access token
2. Request the `publish_stream` and `user_questions` permissions

Then you just need the following code to create a question and publish it to Facebook:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("question", "Cats or dogs?");
JSONObject questions = new JSONObject();
questions.put("Cat");
questions.put("Dog");
params.putString("options", questions.toString())

mAsyncRunner.request("me/questions", params, "POST", new RequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        // success
        Log.d("fb", values.toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, final Object state) {
        Log.e("Facebook", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, final Object state) {
        Log.e("Facebook", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, final Object state) {
        Log.e("Facebook", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }     

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, final Object state) {
        Log.e("Facebook", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: One more question. IS there any way to post the results of a poll/question. For eg I have the question, the options and the number of votes for each options. Now, I want to post this on fb.

Comment: No, you can't prepopulate the results of the options in the question since that would be answering the question on behalf of another user.  You can only create a question + the options, and answer a question for a user, you can't answer a question for multiple users.

Comment: no I did not mean to answer for other users. What if an already conducted poll was there with the results? It is like showing the result. Or do you think posting that on the wall would be enough(hope that too can be done)?

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand your question, but you can definitely post the results to the user's Facebook wall by issuing a POST request to me/feed with the right parameters, it will show up as a regular post/status on the user's profile.